# THREE.js Many instances of the same simple mesh killing framerate

Tags: three.js

I have a basic scene in which I'm using each loops to add multiple meshes ( hundreds of simple cylinders ) to a group (for each line), and grouping the lines to cover the surfaces. The result is this:

[image]

This is the code to add these cylinders:

```
var base_material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
    color: 0x666666, 
    side: THREE.FrontSide,
});
var cylinderGeometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 1, 1, 1, 4 );

var floor_geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 68, 10000, 10 );
var floor = new THREE.Mesh( floor_geometry, base_material );
floor.receiveShadow = true;

scene.add( floor );
floor.position.set(0,-15,-530);
floor.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;

// Add Floor Studs
for ( var i = 0; i < 15; i++ ) {

    var lineGroup = new THREE.Group();

    for ( var n = 0; n < 1000; n++ ) {

        var cylinder = new THREE.Mesh( cylinderGeometry, base_material );

        // cylinder.castShadow = true;
        // cylinder.receiveShadow = true;

        lineGroup.add( cylinder );
        posZ = 0 - n*6;
        cylinder.position.set(0,0, posZ);

    }

    scene.add( lineGroup );
    posX = -28.4 + i*4.1;
    lineGroup.position.set(posX,-14.7,0);

}
```

When I animate the camera to traverse through the scene the framerate is dire. Potential approaches I've come across include merging the geometry, possibly rendering out and loading in a single GLTF model with all of these cylinders, or duplicating them somehow. As you can see the geometry and material is created once and reused, however the mesh is recreated each time which I suspect is the culprit..

My question is, what is the most optimum of these approaches to do this, is there a standard best practice method?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use instancing. https://codepen.io/prisoner849/pen/oNjvOQO Lanterns are instances of one geometry, created with `THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry()`.

Comment: Thanks - I hadn't even come across this in practice. - Even when notching the number of lanterns up to 10k it's still completely smooth. Would this be a better approach than merging geometry which is what I've found to be most successful so far?

Comment: In your specific case, it's better than merging.

Comment: I have opened a new question, although it is related -- is there a way to essentially recreate the lanterns example you kindly put together, but using a standard material instead of a shader mat? That's basically one possible step to resolving the issue described here -- ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61578019/three-js-merging-instancing-multiples-of-the-same-gltf-model-without-shader ). Thanks so much!

Comment: Sure, you can use any material you want, but to use it for instancing, you have to modify it, when use `THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry()`. Or you don't modify it and use it with `THREE.InstancedMesh()`. If you plan to use raycasting, then your choice is `THREE.InstancedMesh()` option.